# how to get values in form field

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a template. this is my template

```
<form id="cal" method="get">
    <span>Number1</span>
    <input type="text" id="number1" name="number1"><br/>
    <span>Number2</span>
    <input type="text" id="number2" name="number2"><br/>
    <input tye"text" id="result">
    <input type="submit" value="calculated">
</form>
```

how to get value number1 and number2, and calculate number1 and number2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
def my_view(request):
    number1 = request.POST.get('number1', None)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST